# How to draw overlapping clusters in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to use GraphViz to draw graphical models. However, I didn't find a way to make draw overlapping clusters. For example, how can I make "nodeA->nodeB" to lie inside both clusterA and clusterB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK you can't.

Clusters as described in the documentation:

> If the name of the subgraph begins with cluster, Graphviz notes the
>   subgraph as a special cluster subgraph. If supported, the layout
>   engine will do the layout so that the **nodes belonging to the cluster
>   are drawn together**, with the entire drawing of the cluster contained
>   within a bounding rectangle.

The whole idea of clusters is *not* to overlap, but to group nodes (and graphviz raises an error when a node is part of two subgraphs).