# Graphviz: Intersecting but non-recursive clusters

Tags: graphviz, intersection, subgraph

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this in Graphviz:[image: description]

As you can see, node "two" is inside two clusters while the clusters aren't recursive.

Note: Image made with Dia.

Comment: Currently not possible

Comment: Reason why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680865/how-to-draw-overlapping-clusters-in-graphviz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680865/how-to-draw-overlapping-clusters-in-graphviz) describes briefly why.

<sub>Just rewriting [Jens'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194473) ans [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6642307) comments as an answer.</sub>

Comment: Is is possible with another tool?

Comment: SaaruLindestøkke do you know such tool?

Comment: @YuriSyro Best to ask a different question (on e.g. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) that shows what research you've done so far and what you're looking for exactly.

Answer (score 3):

While Graphviz won't produce overlapping clusters directly, it will allow you to create overlapping clusters with a bit of editing. (For more info see: https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)

Start with:

```
digraph o {
  graph [newrank=true nodesep=.5]

  subgraph cluster1 {
    graph [margin=50 label="Subgraph 1"]
    {rank=same
      one-> two [style=invis]
    }
  }
  subgraph cluster2 {
    graph [label="Subgraph 2"]
    three
  }
 
  {rank=same
    one two three
  }
}
```

run this command:  `dot -Tdot myfile.gv >myfile.dot`
Then edit myfile.dot to change the boundary box of cluster2.  Like so:

```
digraph o {
    graph [bb="0,0,398,175",
        newrank=true,
        nodesep=.5
    ];
    node [label="\N"];
    {
        graph [rank=same];
        one [height=0.5,
            pos="85,76",
            width=0.75827];
        two [height=0.5,
            pos="176,76",
            width=0.77632];
        three   [height=0.5,
            pos="340,76",
            width=0.99297];
    }
    subgraph cluster1 {
        graph [bb="8,8,254,167",
            label="Subgraph 1",
            lheight=0.21,
            lp="131,155.5",
            lwidth=1.17,
            margin=50
        ];
        {
            graph [rank=same];
            one;
            two;
            one -> two  [pos="e,147.67,76 112.37,76 120.74,76 129.1,76 137.46,76",
                style=invis];
        }
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
        graph [bb="135,50,390,125",  // X1 edited
            label="Subgraph 2",
            lheight=0.21,
            lp="340,113.5",
            lwidth=1.17
        ];
        three;
    }
}
```

run this command on the edited file:  `neato -n2 -Tpng myfile.dot >myfile.png`
Giving:
[image]